# How to create Rest API for the Magento 1.9 hosted in local machine

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I have followed the below steps for authentication for REST API

- http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/

Then I have tried to access this link

- http://127.0.0.2/magento/api/rest/

The error response which I got is

> ```
> <magento_api>
> <messages>
> <error>
> <data_item>
> <code>404</code>
> <message>Request does not match any route.</message>
> </data_item></error>
> </messages>
> </magento_api>
> ```

Please help us how to make it up & reachable , how to get response from the request,
which is the url to access the rest api.

Let me know if I missed anything in the above configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the path is wrong.
Is your base install at http://127.0.0.2 or http://127.0.0.2/magento ?
Try visiting both locations and make sure the base url is viable.

Once that's set. 
Try again, hopefully you get another response like the following:
{\"messages\":{\"error\":[{\"code\":401,\"message\":\"oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_token\"}]}}

Please review the following resources and build on the original question for additional feedback.

Ref:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/testing_rest_resources.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

Comment: Yes http://127.0.0.2/magento is my base url     and tried now i am able to get the response . I am able to access Images, categories & products.

Comment: But how to get read all the api's available in magento

Answer (score 1):

can you try this code as your result

```
<?php
$userData = array("username" => "user_role_name", "password" => "user_role_password");
$ch = curl_init("http://your url/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

$ch = curl_init("http://testrexecom.humcommerce.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2017-01-02 05:40:00.0000000Z&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=2017-11-23T11:06:00.0000000Z&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=to&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=100");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [sample file](https://gist.github.com/rafaelstz/4259811d7dae9f34a80898dd68ab2496) below to connect on you Magento 1 API REST, and following this video: https://youtu.be/Mj1icy_6Cro

```
<?php
// Reference http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-RESTResources

// Custom Resource
$apiResources = "products?limit=2";

// Custom Values
$isAdminUser = true;
$adminUrl = "admin";
$callbackUrl = "http://dev.local3.com/rest.php";
$host = 'http://dev.local3.com/magento/';

$consumerKey    = '7e1339ba397c917f00066fca13543934';
$consumerSecret = '6a3bc1999d9399c655f0b28edbdb8610';

// Don't change
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = $host . "oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = ($isAdminUser) ? $host . $adminUrl . "/oauth_authorize" : $host . "oauth/authorize";
$accessTokenRequestUrl = $host . "oauth/token";
$apiUrl = $host . "api/rest/";
session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();
    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = $apiUrl.$apiResources;
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => '*/*'));
        // $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        $productsList = $oauthClient->getLastResponse();
        // echo "<pre>";
        print_r($productsList);
        // echo "</pre>";
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    echo "<br/>";
    print_r($e->lastResponse);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```